# How to create a new TYPO3 FE User in an Extbase-CommandController-Task

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

We need to synchronise users and therefore plan to pull data from a third party API with the TYPO3 scheduler that updates existing users and adds new users to the `fe_users` table.

Updating existing users works fine, but I don't know how to create a new user. Here is the code I currently use in TYPO3 v8. I don't get any error messages, but the new user is not added to the database.

```php
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\FrontendUserRepository
 */
protected $userRepository;

/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
 */
protected $persistenceManager;

...

$user = $this->userRepository->findOneByForeignId($id);
if ($user) {
    $this->updateUserData($user);
    $this->userRepository->update($user);
} else {
    $user = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser();
    $this->updateUserData($user);
    $this->userRepository->add($user);
}
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();

...

private function updateUserData(&$user)
{
    $user->setFirstName($this->firstName);
    $user->setLastName($this->lastName);
    ...
}
```

I couldn't find any example that creates a new object in a loop. They (here user models) are always injected into the controller action as a parameter.

Comment: Without the code in method `updateUserData()` one can't analyze.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler The method simply updates the data by using the model's setters. I added a part of it to the code.

Comment: Did you check the fe_users table if the records are created? Missing the `pid` could be a reason the users are not created / in the location you are looking for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, I could not tell why the new user could not be created. But you can refer to the log, hopefully it will provide you some tips.

Generally, there could be 2 reasons. One is the `pid`. As you can update the existing users, I think it's not a problem. The other one is the validation. You can not insert a record if the SQL fails.

BTW, I have some similar extensions to do the same things, but not for fe_users table, and they all works.

Comment: `pid` sure can be a problem as existing users have the correct pid. New users not.

Comment: That's right. So, you may need more research on why the `INSERT` doesn't work. BTW, as the `$user` is an object in your code, you don't need `&$user` actually, `$user` would work in `updateUserData`.

Comment: Thanks this was it. The pid was `null` and after setting it (with `$user->setPid($myCoosenPid);`) to the wished page id a new user was added to the database. Strange that there was no error when trying to add a user with pid = null to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Are you shure you must synceonize all users? TYPO3 has a concept called authentication services and an authentication service. Which allow fetching an user while login.

This has multiple advantages:

- instand access you don't need to wait for the next sync to run. Same for blocked users
- privacy a user who never used the typo3 system has no data in it.
- security:potential to avoid storing the users password hash in typo3

Only potential drawback login is not possible if the API is unreachable

See: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Authentication/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for that info but we need those data inside of TYPO3 in order to list the 'users' in the frontend. And the sync is only needed for a short period of time. After that we want to switch completely to TYPO3 and shut down the third party app. So you could say it's a migration of user data.